# Databricks, When should I use ".start()" with writeStream?

Tags: streaming, databricks

I am practicing with Databricks. In sample notebooks, I have seen different use of `writeStream` with or without `.start()` method. I have a few questions in this regard.

Samples are below:

**Without .start():**

```
spark.readStream

     .format("cloudFiles")

     .option("cloudFiles.format", source_format)

     .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_directory)

     .load(data_source)

     .writeStream

     .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_directory)

     .option("mergeSchema", "true")

     .table(table_name)
```

**With .start():**

```
(myDF
 
 .writeStream
 
 .format("delta")
 
 .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
 
 .outputMode("append")
 
 .start(path)
 
)
```

**With .start():**

```
query = (streaming_df.writeStream
                         .foreachBatch(streaming_merge.upsert_to_delta)
                         .outputMode("update")
                         .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_directory)
                         .trigger(availableNow=True)
                         .start())
query.awaitTermination()
```

Q1) I didn't understand where should / shouldn't use `.start()` method. I appreciate it if you could guide me on this.

Q2) If I don't pass `path` to the `start()`, where the data files will be written?